# Difference between running a statement on Evaluate-Expression vs Watches intellij?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, intellij-idea

I am using **intellij-idea** for **Java** development. And also in almost all the other IDEs, there are 2 options, **evaluate-expression** and **watches** to run a statement and see results at debugging time.

Can some one please explain what are the differences between running a statement on these 2? i.e. why there are 2 options provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is that **watches** are evaluated many times, whereas **evaluate expression** is only evaluated manually.

Imagine that you have an expression `object.incrementX()`.

If you set this as a watch expression, and you go through the normal process of debugging (run program, stop at a breakpoint, step, step, etc...) then you will see that the value of `x` is incremented many times.

Wheres if you evaluate the expression then you have control over when it is executed.

The general rule is that if the expression modifies **state** then you should be careful of putting it in a watch expression, else you might get very unpredictable results.

Comment: in your example, incrementX() returns x's value after incremented, right?

Comment: yes, it could, although if it returns void then you can still evaluate the expression (and cause the change in state).

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the Expression Evaluation feature, expressions in watch are persisted as the part of your project.Watch expressions are always evaluated in the context of a stack frame that is currently inspected in the Frames pane.

Whereas Expression Evaluation can only be "single-level".If a method invoked within Expression Evaluation has a breakpoint inside its body, this breakpoint will be ignored.

One of the important difference between Evaluate-Expression and watch is that, while using the Evaluate Expression we can change or modify the params(in case of method) or we can add other logical computations for the same. So along with the watch functionality, it also enables us with the debugging the code on the go by testing various sample cases if required.